# Gson Class Imported by Maven is Not Found When Deployed on JSP and Servlet Java Web

Tags: java, json, maven, jsp, gson

I imported Gson through maven whose code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>HerbTea</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>



</project>
```

However, when I run my program on JSP sevlet program, I receive

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
```

and I don't know why.

You can see the error report [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRW8k.png)

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
________________________________________
Type Exception Report
Message An exception occurred processing [/outcome.jsp] at line [21]
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/outcome.jsp] at line [21]

18:     <% WindowDisplay windowDisplay = (WindowDisplay) request.getSession().getAttribute("windowDisplay");
19:         System.out.println(session.getAttribute(reqSymptomParamKey));
20:         windowDisplay.getRecipeDisplay();
21:         List<Recipe> a = windowDisplay.getRecipeDisplay().retrieveCorrespondingRecipe((List<String>) session.getAttribute(reqSymptomParamKey));
22:         for (Recipe i : windowDisplay.getRecipeDisplay().retrieveCorrespondingRecipe((List<String>) session.getAttribute(reqSymptomParamKey))) {%>
23:     <p1>name:<%=i.getName()%> </p1>
24:     <p1>Corresponding Symptom: <%=i.getSymptomNameList()%></p1>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:617)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:499)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.web.servlet.ServerServlet.doPost(ServerServlet.java:60)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.outcome_jsp._jspService(outcome_jsp.java:178)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.web.servlet.ServerServlet.doPost(ServerServlet.java:60)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
```

The line where the problem occurs according to debugger is this one because any class in Gson package is not found:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
```

Can somebody help me to get over this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson` problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the question answer myself eventually. Thanks for those helping me in editing the question.

The problem is that I didn't add the Maven libaray into the artifact.

The solution will be going into Project Structure->Artifacts->Output layout in Intellij and click on the corresponding Maven imported jar under the "Available Elements" panel to add that Gson libaray jar into the artifact.